# JavaScript: sum of an array using a public method and a private method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the numbers of an array using a public method in which I will pass the array and a private method which will do the addition. The public method will use the private method to do the calculation.

Below is what I have tried

This piece of code does the addition, but I am passing the same array twice i.e in `publicMethod` and `privateMethod` and it just looks redundant.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function publicMethod(arr) {
  //console.log(arr);
  var total = 0;

  function privateMethod(...numbers) {
    console.log('inner');
    for (const number of numbers) {
      console.log('num', number);
      total += number;
      console.log('total', total);
    }
    return total;
  }
  return privateMethod(...arr);
}
// console.log(arr);
console.log(publicMethod(arr));
console.dir(publicMethod);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the same array to the privateMethod since it will get the values from its enclosed closure when it is initialised. You would only need to pass any other variables that are not defined in the enclosed closure

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function publicMethod(arr) {
  //console.log(arr);
  var total = 0;

  function privateMethod() {
    console.log('inner');
    for (const number of arr) {
      console.log('num', number);
      total += number;
      console.log('total', total);
    }
    return total;
  }
  return privateMethod;
}
// console.log(arr);
console.log(publicMethod(arr)());
console.dir(publicMethod(arr));
```

Comment: but when I do `console.dir(publicMethod);` I do not see `closure property` inside the scope.

Comment: arr is passed an an argument to publicMethod and is thus available to `privateMethod` due to closure. Printing the function would show you the available scopes in `[[Scopes]]`

Comment: I tried `console.dir(publicMethod());` still no luck.

Comment: When you do `console.dir(publicMethod());` you aren't returning `privateMethod` and hence you can't log it scope

Comment: oh okay. please point me in the right direction. how do I get it's scope then?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check. You can see the Scopes value in chrome console

Answer (score 1):

You could take the already existend closure over `array` and a local variable of `total` and return the sum.

```js
function publicMethod(array) {

    function privateMethod() {
        var total = 0;
        for (const number of array) {
            total += number;
        }
        return total;
    }

    return privateMethod();
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(publicMethod(arr));
```

Comment: `number of ` is new school though

Answer (score 1):

read about the closures in JavaScript. You don't need to pass the array to the private method. It is already accessible inside the private method.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function publicMethod(arr) {
  //console.log(arr);
  var total = 0;

  function privateMethod() {
    console.log('inner ', arr);
    for (const number of arr) {
      console.log('num', number);
      total += number;
      console.log('total', total);
    }
    return total;
  }
  return privateMethod();
}
// console.log(arr);
console.log(publicMethod(arr));
console.dir(publicMethod);
```